# jquery add images to div based on input field

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add an image 'x' number of times into a div, based on the value of a particular input field.  As the number increases or decreases, I need the images to appear/disappear.  Think I'm way off on this, but here's where I'm at:

```
for(i=0; i<cans; i++) {
    $('.cans').append('<img src="can.png" />');
}
```

where '.cans' is obviously the div container, and 'cans' is the var set to the value of the input field.
any and all help always greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this should work, especially if your input is a select.  If its actually an text input you'll need to do a `keydown` event listener as well.

```
$('input_field_id').change(function(){
    $('.cans').html('');
    var cans = parseInt($(this).val());
    for(i=0; i<cans; i++) {
        $('.cans').append('<img src="can.png" />');
    }
})
```

Comment: thanks for all the quick responses.  this looks like all i need and just meant clearing the html in the .cans block to my code.  i was actually using an input range slider and initial tests are showing that it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input').on('change keydown',function(){ //add a change listener
    var count = parseInt($(this).val()); //store the value in a variable as a number
    if (!isNaN(count)){ //check if the value is actually a numer
        $('.cans').html(''); //clear previous images from the element
        for (var i=0; i<count; i++) $('.cans').append('<img src="can.png" />');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text"/>
<div class="cans"></div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
  $('input[type=text]').on('change',function(){
      $('.cans').empty();  //Remove all child nodes
      var value = $(this).val();
      for(i=0; i<parseInt(value); i++) {
        $('.cans').append('<img src="can.png" />');
      }
   });
```

Check out [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kWH6U/).

`$('.cans').empty();  //Remove all child nodes` **so no need for decrement**